# Check filter found any item and get first item

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to check if anything found by `filter` on `Stream` and if found return the first item. I have tried this:

```
Stream<String> res= Stream.of("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1")
.filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"));

if(res.anyMatch(i->true))
     System.out.println(res.findFirst().get());
```

but it give me following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: `findFirst` and `findAny` are both terminal operations (stream basics) and moreover their behavior overlaps a lot: one finds the first and the other could find the first, or another one if that turns out to be computationally faster. `anyMatch` is just a special interpretation of `findAny`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out,

```
final String firstMatch = Stream.of("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1")
                                .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElse(null);
```

You can't reuse the stream once it is created. That's why you are getting that error. You first reuse the stream and call a terminal operation `res.anyMatch(i -> true)` and then another terminal operation `res.findFirst()` leading this error. This is an antipattern and should be avoided.

A Stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. A Stream implementation may throw `IllegalStateException` if it detects that the Stream is being reused.

**Update**

As per the below comment, this can further be simplified as,

```
Stream.of("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1").filter(s -> s.startsWith("c")).findFirst()
                .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Better `.findFirst() .ifPresent(System.out::println);` instead of creating the need for a subsequent `null`-check.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome feedback ! How about using `.findAny()` instead of `.findFirst()`? `.findAny()` is also a short circuit operation which is more parallel friendly.

Comment: Only the OP can tell whether the different semantic of `findAny()` is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Use `findFirst` and `ifPresent`:

```
Stream.of("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1")
      .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

or if you want to perform another operation if `findFirst()` returns an empty `Optional<T>` then use

```
Optional<String> result =
    Stream.of("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1")
          .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
          .findFirst();
if(result.isPresent()){ System.out.println(result.get());}
else{ System.out.println("nothing found");};
```

or as of JDK9-

```
 Stream.of("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1")
       .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
       .findFirst()
       .ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println, () -> System.out.println("nothing found"));
```